# Uncaught ReferenceError: saveData is not defined in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3), using Ruby on Rails instead of PHP and MySQL (class requirements). I can right-click on the map to add a marker, left-click on the marker to make an infowindow popup, and I can fill out the infowindow, but when I click 'Save & Close' I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: saveData is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://localhost:4000/#/user:1:1)onclick @ VM83 user:1

Using `debugger`, I can confirm that `saveData()` never gets called.

What do I need to do to save the inputted info on the infowindow? Also, if you have input on my promise chain in mapController.js below (is it correct, etc).

### Things I Have Tried

- remove `async defer` from index.html script tag per stackOverflow suggestion.
- re `onclick='saveData()'`, I have removed the quotes and the parentheses in all permutations.
- I manually typed out the line where `onclick='saveData()'` is found.
- I moved the saveData function inside the initiliaze function per stackOverflow suggestion.
- I renamed it to `infowindow.saveData()` per stackOverflow suggestion.
- moved saveData() above initialize().
- changed all `let`s to `var`s
- added `onload='initialize()'` to div tag in _user.html, several permutations including nested divs, moving `ng-controller`, etc.
- moved code from mapController.js to _user.html inside a script tag.

### My Code

#### _user.html

```
<div ng-controller="mapController as map" id="map" style="width:100%; height:80vh;"></div>
```

#### mapController.js

```
angular.module('tour').controller('mapController', function() {
let self = this,
marker,
infowindow;
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0902, -95.7129);
  var options = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
  var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr><td>Title:</td> <td><input type='text' id='title'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Description:</td> <td><input type='text' id='description'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Audio URL:</td> <td><input type='url' id='audio'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Category:</td> <td><select id='category'>" +
             "<option value='art' SELECTED>art</option>" +
             "<option value='history'>history</option>" +
             "<option value='literature'>literature</option>" +
             "<option value='music'>music</option>" +
             "</select> </td></tr>" +
             "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: html
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }); // end addListener
  }); // end addListener
} // end initialize function

function saveData() {
  var marker = {
    title: escape(document.getElementById("title").value),
    description: escape(document.getElementById("description").value),
    audio: document.getElementById("audio").value,
    category: document.getElementById("category").value,
    longitude: marker.lng(),
    latitude: marker.lat()
  }

  return $http({
    url: `${rootUrl}/users/:id/add_marker`,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {marker: marker},
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    }
  })
  .then(function(res){
    let markers = self.currentUser.markers;
    let newMarker = res.config.data.marker;
    markers.unshift(newMarker); // adds to beginning of array
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log('ERROR ~>', error);
  });
}

initialize();
});
```

Comment: Try defining it as follows: `window.saveData = function(){ /* your code here */ };` ... I know, it is a work-around. I think problem is related to angular and $scope usage

Comment: @leo.fcx I think this is working, but now I'm trying to get my promise chain to do what I want.  Once I get the bugs out I'll let you know for sure.  Thanks!

Comment: As I said, I think you should review angular documentation to make the code better. Publishing your saveData function in the global context is not a good idea

Comment: @leo.fcx Now I'm getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:4000/users/:id/add_marker. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`  I have nodemon and rails server running, and cors.rb is setup, otherwise I wouldn't be able to do any Angular/Rails stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.saveData = function(){ /* your code here */ }
onclick="window.saveData()"
```